# How to apply SMOTE on multivarite time series data?

Tags: time-series, imbalanced-data, smote

I am new to multivarite time series problems. My data is imbalanced and I want to balance the data so I tried to apply `imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE` on the raw time series data but it failed. How to apply SMOTE on multivariate time series data and is there any other python package can do the same thing? I did not find any related tutorials.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.